# google inapp details in android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

i working on google inapp,
below is my code i want to get all information of my all inapp product, but how to compare the arraylist object with a string,it shows error on for loop "cannot convert element type object to string"

```
ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
       skuList.add("premiumUpgrade"); 
       skuList.add("gas");
       Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
       querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

       Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),"inapp", querySkus);

       int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
       if (response == 0)
       {
           ArrayList responseList 
              = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

           for (String thisResponse : responseList)
           {
               JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
               String sku = object.getString("productId");
               String price = object.getString("price");
               if (sku.equals("premiumUpgrade")) 
               {
                  // mPremiumUpgradePrice = price;
                   Log.i("price", price);
               } else if (sku.equals("gas")) { 
                  // mGasPrice = price;
                   Log.i("price", price);
               }
           }
       }
```

Comment: can u give us the line of error and the related crash log?

Comment: its on the for loop, it dont allow to use responselist in for loop,becz its an arraylist,it shows "cannot convert element type object to string"

Answer (score 0):

Ok have you try to do that: add STRING to the definition of ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> responseList 
              = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");
```

because you do not define what is inside your array list it can't cast blindly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue for a while. What fixed it for me was making sure my version code and version name in my manifest matched the one on my google play dev console.

Technically, for these services to work, your app has to be "published", but matching the version code and version name to the code and name of the version you have published will also do the trick.

hope this helps! :)